# The element is already the child of another element

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, children

I am working on a big silverlight project where i had a problem so i  break up the problem on to the smaller problem to ask at stackoverflow.

I have a big grid (LayoutRoot) in this code. Inside this LayoutRoot i have  more then 2 rows(i will just use 2 rows out of more then 2 rows). On the first row i will have combo box and on the another
row i will have display of text (in two different rows) on combo selectionChnged event but please take care the display of the text has to be in two different rows in for loop
Bceause in the bigger program i have similar kind of situation where each if condition in for loop will retuirn a grid contaning some data/UI element on it and i store each grid in different column one after the other and again store that all rows in a big Grid.

It will ofcourse give "already have children exception" on second time execution of for loop at line "storeRowGridInBig.Children.Add(rowGrid);"
  But the problem is how to solve it  now ? (what i have to do is : In my each if condition in for loop wil return a grid on each iteration of for loop and those girds are
  supposed to be displayed row by row) How to solve this problem ?

My try to do this is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication6
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
            Grid largeGrid = new Grid();
            for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
            {
                largeGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                largeGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { });
                cmb.Items.Add(i);
            }   

            cmb.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Grid rowGrid = new Grid();
                    Grid storeRowGridInBig = new Grid();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++ )
                        rowGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
                            txt1.Text = "for 1";
                            rowGrid.Children.Add(txt1);                                            
                        }
                        else if (i == 1)
                        {
                            TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
                            txt1.Text = "for 2";
                            rowGrid.Children.Add(txt1);                          
                        }
                        Grid.SetRow(rowGrid, i);
                        storeRowGridInBig.Children.Add(rowGrid);     //on puting it outside it shows both the text in 1 line overwrites I dont know why ?)         
                    }                  
                    Grid.SetRow(storeRowGridInBig, 1);
                    largeGrid.Children.Add(storeRowGridInBig);
                };

            Grid.SetRow(cmb,0);
            Grid.SetColumn(cmb, 1);
            largeGrid.Children.Add(cmb);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(largeGrid);
        }
    }
}
```

And :

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication6.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How to solve the current situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you add the same control multiple times to its parent in the line:

```
storeRowGridInBig.Children.Add(rowGrid);
```

Put it outside the for-loop and it should work

**But the correct way would be not to add any controls in Code-behind**

Take a look at `MVVM` design pattern

**Update:**

Rewrote your method so it should work, but it is really not a clean solution:

```
  cmb.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
  {
    Grid rowGrid = new Grid();
    Grid storeRowGridInBig = new Grid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      rowGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      if (i == 0)
      {
        TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
        txt1.Text = "for 1";
        rowGrid.Children.Add(txt1);
        Grid.SetRow(txt1, i);
      }
      else if (i == 1)
      {
        TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
        txt1.Text = "for 2";
        rowGrid.Children.Add(txt1);
        Grid.SetRow(txt1, i);
      }
    }

    storeRowGridInBig.Children.Add(rowGrid);

    Grid.SetRow(storeRowGridInBig, 1);
    if (LayoutRoot.Children.Count > 1)
    {
      LayoutRoot.Children.RemoveAt(LayoutRoot.Children.Count - 1);
    }
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(storeRowGridInBig);
  };
```

There were several problems:

- You added `rowGrid` multiple times
- You used `Grid.SetRow` on `rowGrid` instead of `txt1`
- When `SelectionChanged` was called another time, the grid you added in the previous run was not removed

Comment: sorry could you please explain in detail ?

Comment: I have made only 1 child to LayoutRoot which contain 2 grids but stillt he same problem .And in my bigger project i am using MVVM.

Comment: If i put it poutside It prints both the text in same row , insted of  2 different rows. If you do not trust me please  check i have updated the full code.

Comment: I would really thank if you explain also that what was the problme before and how you elmiminated problem ? Thanks lot reallly .